# Replyto PHP MAILER

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hola estoy usando phpmailer para mandar correos por un formulario

Me di cuenta que cuando me llegaban los correos me llegan con la direccion de mi servidor SMTP puse el replyto pero aun sigue llegando con el correo del servidor y lo estoy usando como la libreria indica

```
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 //Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
 $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
 $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
 $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
 $mail->Username   = 'admin@ucarolina.mx';                     // SMTP username
 $mail->Password   = EMAIL_PASSWORD;                             // SMTP password
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';                                   // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
 $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to


    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($email,$name);
    $mail->addAddress('luribe@qvoz.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo(); 
    $mail->addReplyTo($email);
    // Add a recipient

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $contact_message;
    $mail->AltBody = $contact_message;
```

Comment: Revisando, cuando me llega el correo si le doy al boton de responder si me pone el correo correcto, pero si le doy doble click al nombre del usuario que mando el correo me pone el correo incorrecto

Answer (score 1):

la llamada al método `addReplyTo($emailEmisor)` tiene que ir por delante de las llamadas a los métodos `setFrom($emailEmisor, $nombreEmisor)` y `addAddress($emailReceptor)`.

```
//Recipients
   $mail->addReplyTo($email);
   $mail->setFrom($email,$name);
   $mail->addAddress('luribe@qvoz.com');
```

Espero qué sea de ayuda.

Comment: Esto era en versiones antiguas de PHPMailer, ya no es necesario seguir ese orden hace años